# Accessing Firefox 3 cookies in Python

Tags: python, cookies, firefox-3

I'm trying to make a python script that will access a website with the cookies in Firefox. cookielib.MozillaCookieJar would work if it supported Firefox 3. Is there a way to access Firefox 3 cookies inside of python?

I see that there are two files under [home]/.mozilla/firefox/[randomletters].default/ called cookies.sqlite and cookies-nontor.xml. The .xml file looks like it would be easy to write a function that will return a CookieJar from it, but if there's already a module that does this, then I'd like to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a recipe](http://blog.mithis.net/archives/python/90-firefox3-cookies-in-python) for accessing the SQLite cookies in FF 3. There's a patch at the [Python bug Tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue2277) and [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) also supports this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there an example of using mechanize to get the browser cookies? I saw an example in the documentation for the old cookies.txt, but not for the new cookies.sqlite.

Comment: I was able to find this early explanation: http://osdir.com/ml/python.wwwsearch.general/2008-02/msg00012.html

Comment: After trying mechanize quite a bit, I had no luck... But after using the recipe you linked to, I've had great success.

Answer (score 1):

I created a module to load cookies from Firefox, available here: https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browser_cookie/

Example usage:

```
import requests
import browser_cookie
cj = browser_cookie.firefox()
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
```

Answer (score 1):

[TryPyPy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4602107/343302) got me on the right track, but the code in the linked recipe was outdated and would not work with Python3. Here is **Python3** code that will read the cookie jar from a running Firefox and use it when querying web pages:

```
import requests

url = 'http://github.com'
cookie_file = '/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/f00b4r.default/cookies.sqlite'



def get_cookie_jar(filename):
    """
    Protocol implementation for handling gsocmentors.com transactions
    Author: Noah Fontes nfontes AT cynigram DOT com
    License: MIT
    Original: http://blog.mithis.net/archives/python/90-firefox3-cookies-in-python

    Ported to Python 3 by Dotan Cohen
    """

    from io import StringIO
    import http.cookiejar
    import sqlite3

    con = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT host, path, isSecure, expiry, name, value FROM moz_cookies")

    ftstr = ["FALSE","TRUE"]

    s = StringIO()
    s.write("""\
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
""")

    for item in cur.fetchall():
        s.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (
            item[0], ftstr[item[0].startswith('.')], item[1],
            ftstr[item[2]], item[3], item[4], item[5]))

    s.seek(0)
    cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
    cookie_jar._really_load(s, '', True, True)

    return cookie_jar



cj = get_cookie_jar(cookie_file)
response = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
print(response.text)
```

Tested on Kubuntu Linux 14.10 with Python 3.4.2 and Firefox 39.0. The code is also available from [my Github repo](https://github.com/dotancohen/pytility/blob/master/read-firefox-cookies.py).