# Is it possible to retrieve cookies after logging in through a browser?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

I know it's possible to use requests.Session() from the requests module to handle cookies. Instead, I want to know if there's a way to obtain login authentication by letting the user login themselves through a browser and then retrieving their session cookies after successful login.

Comment: Have you considered using mechanize?

Comment: This post will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606072/python-how-to-dump-cookies-of-a-mechanize-browser-instance

Comment: Or this one: [accessing-firefox-3-cookies-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602048/accessing-firefox-3-cookies-in-python/33078599#33078599), for FF

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out